# C# Regex for string that doesn't start with 4 chars

Tags: c#, regex

I have the basic pattern:

```
Input = Regex.Replace(Input, "#(.+?)#", "<h3>$1</h3>");
```

Now I only want this to match IF the line it's on DOESN'T start with 4 space characters.  For example:

```
This line #would match#
    #this one# wouldn't
```

I've got as far as:

```
Input = Regex.Replace(Input, "^( {4}).?#(.+?)#", "<h3>$2</h3>");
```

But this doesn't seem to work; it doesn't replace properly.  Here's some test data:

```
#This is my header#

Some text, code below:

    background:#333333;
    background: #ffffff, #000000;

Testing text

#Another header#

Text
```

Comment: You seem to want to isolate/prevent this 'background: `#ffffff, #`000000;' from being replaced. But the criteria is weak at best. Relying on four space to prevent this AND add <h3> tags requires a very strict format. If thats the case then this is OK. Otherwise, the only thing reliable would be something like this `s~^\s*\#([^\#\n]*)\#\s*$~<h3>$1</h3>~`. Even that requires a strict format. There has to be heavy emphisis on what qualifies `between` pound signs (my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookbehind to assert that four spaces have not appeared in the input, like so:

```
"(?<!^    )#(.+?)#"
```

But it would probably more readable to just check before applying the regex.

```
if (!Input.StartsWith("    "))
    Input = Regex.Replace(Input, "#(.+?)#", "<h3>$1</h3>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply check for the existance of 4 spaces?

```
 if(line.StartsWith("    "))
 {
     var text = line.Substring(4, line.Length - 4);
     text = "<h3>" + text + "</h3>";
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing as the original code, but the idea is good.

Answer (score 1):

```
Input = Regex.Replace(Input, "^(?! {4})(.*?)#(.+?)#", "$1<h3>$2</h3>");
```

First, assert that the line doesn't start with four spaces: `^(?! {4})`.

Then capture whatever it *does* start with, if it's not the stuff you're actually matching: `(.*?)`.

And finally, plug the initial characters (which could be simply an empty string) back in before you do the real replacement: `$1<h3>$2</h3>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex searches for lines which *do* start with four spaces -- that's why it doesn't work.

You can solve your problem with a negative lookahead:

```
Input = Regex.Replace(Input, "^(?! {4})(.*)#(.+?)#", "$1<h3>$2</h3>");
```

This matches lines that, from the beginning (`^`),

- do not start with four spaces `(?! {4})`,
- the remainder until `#...#` is captured in group 1 `(.*)`
- #...# is captured in group 2 `#(.+?)#`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Input = Regex.Replace(Input, "(?<!\\s{4})#(.+?)#", "<h3>$1</h3>");
```